# How to generate custom build errors in Visual Studio 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, build-automation

I'm trying to integrate a custom c++ unit test framework into my build process, and would like the unit tests to run as a final step in the build.  Presently I'm executing the unit test in a post-build execution of a batch file, which outputs the test results to the console.  If any test fails, the post build step exits with status 1.

This produces a build error in the Error List pane, as desired, but I'm looking for a way to customize the error message content to show that some unit tests failed.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact this is the method used by the [Boost.Test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/test/) library.

I'm not sure of the exact format requirements but output like:

`c:\path\to\file.cpp(line_number) : message`

should get added to the error pane in the IDE.

Comment: Any idea how Boost is doing that?  Does sound like what I want.

Comment: @davex_ Other than by writing output in the correct format, I don't know.  Sorry.  Have a look at compile warnings/errors in the Output window in MSVC for examples.